# How to apply grid on card elements without ruining vertical alignment in reducing browser size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, material-design

I came across this card UI http://codepen.io/mkurapov/pen/qNQXxz that displays three cards and if you make the browser smaller, it realigns the cards to be a vertical line.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="tile"> 
  <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464054313797-e27fb58e90a9?dpr=1&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=1500&h=996&q=80'/>
  <div class="text">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum.</h1>
  <h2 class="animate-text">More lorem ipsum bacon ipsum.</h2>
  <p class="animate-text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet pork belly tri-tip turducken, pancetta bresaola pork chicken meatloaf. Flank sirloin strip steak prosciutto kevin turducken. </p>
<div class="dots">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>


<div class="tile"> 
  <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1458668383970-8ddd3927deed?dpr=1&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1004&q=80'/>
  <div class="text">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum.</h1>
  <h2 class="animate-text">More lorem ipsum bacon ipsum.</h2>
  <p class="animate-text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet pork belly tri-tip turducken, pancetta bresaola pork chicken meatloaf. Flank sirloin strip steak prosciutto kevin turducken. </p>
<div class="dots">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>

  <div class="tile"> 
  <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1422393462206-207b0fbd8d6b?dpr=1&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80'/>
  <div class="text">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum.</h1>
  <h2 class="animate-text">More lorem ipsum bacon ipsum.</h2>
  <p class="animate-text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet pork belly tri-tip turducken, pancetta bresaola pork chicken meatloaf. Flank sirloin strip steak prosciutto kevin turducken. </p>
<div class="dots">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
  background-color:#eee
}
.wrap
{
  margin:50px auto 0 auto;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:space-around;
  max-width:1200px;
}
.tile
{
  width:380px;
  height:380px;
  margin:10px;
  background-color:#99aeff;
  display:inline-block;
  background-size:cover;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0px 35px 77px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.44);
  overflow:hidden;
  color:white;
  font-family:'Roboto';

}
.tile img
{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}
.tile .text
{
/*   z-index:99; */
  position:absolute;
  padding:30px;
  height:calc(100% - 60px);
}
.tile h1
{

  font-weight:300;
  margin:0;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.tile h2
{
  font-weight:100;
  margin:20px 0 0 0;
  font-style:italic;
   transform: translateX(200px);
}
.tile p
{
  font-weight:300;
  margin:20px 0 0 0;
  line-height: 25px;
/*   opacity:0; */
  transform: translateX(-200px);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.animate-text
{
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.tile:hover
{
/*   background-color:#99aeff; */
box-shadow: 0px 35px 77px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.64);
  transform:scale(1.05);
}
.tile:hover img
{
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.tile:hover .animate-text
{
  transform:translateX(0);
  opacity:1;
}
.dots
{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:20px;
  right:30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  color:currentColor;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-around;

}

.dots span
{
    width: 5px;
    height:5px;
    background-color: currentColor;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display:block;
  opacity:0;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-out, opacity 0.5s ease;
  transform: translateY(30px);

}

.tile:hover span
{
  opacity:1;
  transform:translateY(0px);
}

.dots span:nth-child(1)
{
   transition-delay: 0.05s;
}
.dots span:nth-child(2)
{
   transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.dots span:nth-child(3)
{
   transition-delay: 0.15s;
}


@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .wrap {
   flex-direction: column;
    width:400px;
  }
}
```

I am interested in learning about how to add more cards from the initial three, however if you adding more cards to the code it smushes the cards and no longer retains its squarish design.

I am curious what ways can you add the grid without losing the vertical alignment when you reduce the web browser's size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add a wrap rule:

```
.wrap
{
  margin:50px auto 0 auto;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:space-around;
  max-width:1200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap; <-- boop
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgxBQK